# Safari end-of-life

Tags: safari

I went looking for information on when specific versions of Safari would be end-of-life'd.

I did google and support.apple.com, but could not find anything. Maybe Apple is going to end-of-life via the OS a version lives on?

Comment: +1 ... simply because the downvoter didn't leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks Molly. Can't imagine why they would think the question is unimportant, unless they didn't actually do any web properties for a living...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Sept 19th, 2017:

The "security conscious" answer should be that Safari 10 was replaced by Safari 11 for:

- OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
- macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- macOS High Sierra 10.13

[Apple security updates](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222)

Note:

- Safari 10.1.12 was the last updated on July 12th, 2017.
- Safari 11 is not available on Yosemite. (I have a fully updated Yosemite version, I can confirm Safari 10.1.12 does not upgrade to Safari 11.)
- Safari 10.1.12 presumably lacks all the [new security fixes in Safari 11](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208116).

Comment: Also, if you are fleeing older macOS (like Yosemite), to El Capitan or macOS Sierra, you might end up losing Safari 10, and getting Safari 9. (App Store Updates also seems to take its time recognizing you need to re-upgrade to get Safari 11.x.

Answer (score 1):

Apple hasn't published EoL dates for their OSes. Here's a [post on the subject](https://web.archive.org/web/20150513062224/http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2009/Jun/msg00221.html).

In general, 10.X and 10.X-1 are supported. The last time a security update was posted for 10.4 was in September, shortly after Snow Leopard (10.6) came out. Earlier this month there was a security update for 10.5 and 10.6, but nothing for 10.4.

iTunes requires 10.4 at a minimum now, as does current Safari.